# How do I adjust the microphone volume in Zoom?

Tags: microphone, zoom-meeting

How do I adjust my microphone volume in Zoom Meetings, if people complain that I am too loud / too quiet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the green shield icon during the meeting. A large menu appears. Click on the 'audio' setting.  You can from there adjust and test the microphone, and turn automatic volume setting on or off.[image]